# python regex function split string with special character

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I know this is probably asked somewhere but I can't seem to find an answer for this question

so I have a string like string = Pogo03.1Name, or string = Togo05.2Number

I want split the string this way like [Pogo03, '.1', 'Name'] and [Togo05, '.2', 'Number']

I tried doing this

```
pattern = re.findall(r'.[0-9], string)
re.split(pattern, string)
```

but I keep getting ['Pogo', '3', '.', 'Name']

After some research I know because . is used as special character, now my question is how do I split by including the special character while using regex to find the random number (.n)

Thanks

Comment: Does preceding with an escape char (\\\) not work?

Comment: ok after tried few times, yes puting escape char does work, I just cannot use re.split but instead of regular string.split() function after. Thanks for the help